# Why the callback in the index.py file not working (tring to built a multipage app using dash)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

#https://github.com/ikram-12/App_Dash1
I am new to Plotly Dash and trying to develop a multi-page App.
I can't seem to identify the error in the callback function?
It's not showing any error.
Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# Connect to main app.py file
from app import app
from app import server

# Connect to your app pages
from apps import test_page1, test_page2

app.layout = html.Div([
dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
html.Div([
    dcc.Link('R|', href='/apps/R'),
    dcc.Link('Other Products', href='/apps/test_page2'),
], className="row"),
html.Div(id='page-content', children=[]),
])

 @app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
          [Input('url', 'pathname')])
 def display_page(pathname):
if pathname == '/apps/R':
    return test_page1.layout
if pathname == '/apps/test_page2':
    return test_page2.layout
else:
    return "choose a page"

 if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: First set `debug` to `True` when testing. Most likely Dash will then display some clear error messages when running the app. You can also look in the console of the browser or the network tab for errors.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. The error was "In the callback for output(s):
  t.figure
Output 0 (t.figure) is already in use.
Any given output can only have one callback that sets it.
." Cause I was using the same Id for two different output for two different callbacks.